# I am getting an error in insert statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to insert in `Keyword` and `SearchResults` table. I am getting an error while trying to insert into **SearchResults** table.

```
Declare @UrlList SearchResultList READONLY
declare @KeywordID int

insert into Keyword(Keyword,Domain_ID,RunDate)values(@Keyword,@Domain_ID,@RunDate)
set @KeywordID=IDENT_CURRENT('Keyword')


insert into SearchResults(SearchedURL,Keyword_ID,IsClient)
select (select SearchedURL from @UrlList),@KeywordID as Keyword_ID,1 as IsClient
```

I am getting an error which is given below.

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
>   The statement has been terminated.

```html
<table><tbody><tr><th>SearchedURL_ID</th><th>SearchedURL</th><th>Keyword_ID</th><th>IsClient</th></tr><tr><td>8</td><td>http://www.revanadigital.com/</td><td>8</td><td>NULL</td></tr><tr><td>9</td><td>http://www.zoominfo.com/c/WebMetro-Inc/41713725</td><td>8</td><td>NULL</td></tr><tr><td>10</td><td>http://www.revanadigital.com/who-we-are/careers/</td><td>8</td><td>NULL</td></tr><tr><td>11</td><td>https://www.glassdoor.com/Reviews/WebMetro-California-Reviews-E259626.htm</td><td>8</td><td>NULL</td></tr><tr><td>12</td><td>http://www.yelp.com/biz/webmetro-san-dimas</td><td>8</td><td>NULL</td></tr><tr><td>13</td><td>https://www.crunchbase.com/organization/webmetro</td><td>8</td><td>NULL</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Comment: The error message it clear: that `(select SearchedURL ..` should return a single value. You can't insert a list of values into that column in that single row.

Comment: Can u suggest how to insert multiple value?

Comment: You already have two answers with full source which insert _multiple values_. Or this is not what you want and your aim is to concatenate all urls from `@urllist` into one string?

Comment: What is (sample) input you have, what is the result that you want to get (based on that input)? Please edit your question to add that info.

Comment: please run code snippet.

Comment: Hi Ivan, I don't want to concatenate all urls from `@urlList`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to insert all urls with obtained @keywordid, then you need this:

```
insert into SearchResults(SearchedURL,Keyword_ID,IsClient)
select SearchedURL,@KeywordID as Keyword_ID,1 as IsClient
from @UrlList
```

if not then you have to modify `(select SearchedURL from @UrlList)` subquery to ensure it returns only one row. Add `TOP 1` with `ORDER BY` or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

Your second insert query should be like this -

```
INSERT INTO SearchResults (SearchedURL, Keyword_ID, IsClient)
    SELECT SearchedURL ,@KeywordID ,1 FROM @UrlList
```

You can refer this MSDN link - [How to use TVP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)